# Creating Array for Task.WhenAll()

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I want to call the same method (task) an unknown number of times, only with different parameters. I came across Task.WhenAll () and as I understood, I need to pass an array of tasks to it. Let's say I have an array with parameters for which I need to run asynchronously. I thought a little and wanted to write code like this:

```cs
List<Task> list = new List<Task>();

foreach(var data in Data)
{
    list.Add(MyTask(data));
}
Task.WhenAll(list.ToArray());
```

But it seems that this piece of code will only call the task in the 5th line and write only the results to the `list`. And I had a question, how else can I call the group
from the same method with different parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Task.WhenAll` returns a new `Task` that completes when all the provided `Task`s have completed, so you need to `await` this:

```
await Task.WhenAll(list);
```

Note that the `ToArray` is superfluous, because `Task.WhenAll` has an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__) that accepts `IEnumerable<Task>`.

The list is also unnecessary, you can simply project your `Data`:

```
await Task.WhenAll(Data.Select(MyTask));
```